# Crash when retrofit SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

When my users login success, i do many request to syn my local database.
I do this with retrofit and user RxJava to zip the response.

But when i have a SocketTimeoutException my application crash, and i don't know why.

This is my code :

```
private fun syncData(): Single<Boolean> {


    getProgressTextView().text = getString(R.string.synchronizing)

    val list: List<Single<Boolean>> = Arrays.asList(DocumentTypeManager.getAndSave(retrofit),
            HomeAccessibilitiesManager.getAndSave(retrofit),
            StreetTypesManager.getAndSave(retrofit),
            IncidentTypesManager.getAndSave(retrofit),
            TaskTypesManager.getAndSave(retrofit, this),
            PatientFunituresManager.getAndSave(retrofit, this),
            HealthMutualsManager.getAndSave(retrofit))



    return Single.zip(list, {

        it.forEach {
            if (!(it as Boolean)) {
                return@zip false
            }
        }
        return@zip true

    })

}
```

an example of an object that get the httpRequest

```
object HomeAccessibilitiesManager : AnkoLogger {

fun getAndSave(retrofit: Retrofit): Single<Boolean> {

    val t = retrofit.create(RestApi::class.java)
            .getHomeAccessibilities()

    return HttpRequestDataManager.getAndSave(t)


}
```

}

the manager that save my webService return in database

```
 object HttpRequestDataManager : AnkoLogger {


inline fun <reified T : io.realm.RealmModel> getAndSave(single: Single<List<T>>): Single<Boolean> {

    return Single.create { subscriber ->


        single
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        { list ->


                            executeTransaction {

                                list.saveAll()

                            }

                            debug { "success sync, with ${list.size} results" }
                            subscriber.onSuccess(true)

                        },


                        {

                            if (it != null) {
                                warn { it.message }
                                subscriber.onError(it)
                            } else {
                                subscriber.onError(Throwable("unknow error"))
                            }
                        }
                )
    }
}
```

}

and the RestApi

```
@GET("api/v1/home_accessibilities")
fun getHomeAccessibilities(): Single<List<RHomeAccessibilities>>
```

i also have an JWTInterceptor

```
class JwtInterceptor(val context: Context) : Interceptor, AnkoLogger {

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

    val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()

    if (UserManager.jwtToken.isNotEmpty()) {

        builder.header("Authorization", String.format("%s %s", "Bearer", UserManager.jwtToken))

    }

    val response = chain.proceed(builder.build())
    if (response.code() == 401 && UserManager.islogged) {

        UserManager.logout()

        executeTransaction {
            debug { "deleting all database" }
            it.deleteAll()
        }


        val intent = Intent(context, LoginActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        context.startActivity(intent)

        context.runOnUiThread { context.toast(context.getString(R.string.session_expired)) }


    }

    return response

}
```

}

and the logs :

```
05-22 09:31:25.771 21960-22425/com.sanilea.itineraire D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out
05-22 09:31:25.771 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/HttpRequestDataManager: SSL handshake timed out
05-22 09:31:25.772 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out
05-22 09:31:25.774 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate$Emitter.onError(SingleCreate.java:82)
    at com.sanilea.itineraire.managers.StreetTypesManager$getAndSave$$inlined$getAndSave$1$2.accept(HttpRequestDataManager.kt:52)
    at com.sanilea.itineraire.managers.StreetTypesManager$getAndSave$$inlined$getAndSave$1$2.accept(HttpRequestDataManager.kt:21)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onError(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:47)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:79)
    at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-22 09:31:25.775 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
05-22 09:31:25.776 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
05-22 09:31:25.777 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out
05-22 09:31:25.778 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:351)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:302)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:270)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:162)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
05-22 09:31:25.779 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
05-22 09:31:25.780 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
05-22 09:31:25.781 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
05-22 09:31:25.782 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
05-22 09:31:25.783 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
05-22 09:31:25.786 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:212)
05-22 09:31:25.787 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
05-22 09:31:25.790 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
05-22 09:31:25.791 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at com.sanilea.itineraire.http.JwtInterceptor.intercept(JwtInterceptor.kt:36)
05-22 09:31:25.792 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
05-22 09:31:25.793 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:42)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10981)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10981)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2801)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
05-22 09:31:25.794 21960-21960/com.sanilea.itineraire W/System.err:
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
05-22 09:31:25.798 21960-22426/com.sanilea.itineraire D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out
05-22 09:31:25.802 21960-21965/com.sanilea.itineraire I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=78KB
05-22 09:31:25.809 21960-21965/com.sanilea.itineraire I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=78KB
05-22 09:31:25.810 21960-21965/com.sanilea.itineraire I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from my emulator, it was totaly broken...